# using background image in css grid

Tags: css

I try to use background image within css grid, but I cannot see the images

```
.firstPage {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "homePageImage1 homePageImage2"
}

.homePageImage1 {
  grid-area: homePageImage1;
  background-image: url('https://postimg.cc/F12QYFjW');
  width: 700px;
  height: 962px;
}

.homePageImage2 {
  grid-area: homePageImage2;
  background-image: url("https://postimg.cc/LJQDs5Ph");
  width: 666px;
  height: 962px;  
}

<div class="firstPage" style="width: 1366px;">
  <div class="homePageImage1">
  </div>
  <div class="homePageImage2">
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/09csye6f/40/

Comment: you are not using links for images but links for web pages showing the images: https://postimg.cc/F12QYFjW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the url of the image not the site, for example https://i.postimg.cc/gk0cBnrW/home-Page-Image1.png instead of https://postimg.cc/F12QYFjW

**EDIT**:
After checking your files, the problem was that the `url` was not finding the relative local paths of the images since you specifically specified a `base` one in the top of your head. So, the solution is to simply remove `<base href="/">`. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: Sorry, I updated the fiddle and it works, but the html file on my browser does not show the images

Comment: I tried it locally in a ``.html`` file and it worked. Make sure that nothing else in your file is hiding the images.

Comment: I can see the image when I click on it in firebug, I changed the image, I checked the permission of the file, but nothing works

Comment: Attach the whole code in the question or link the file, in order for me to test it.

Comment: I used google drive to share the files. You will have to touch up the html file for the use of background image url

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GrsZaWr6cO5gXyZ8JyZG6-rieGDN5Iz0

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HrdR1kC3kFpqhlQY8y0VXO2053P6thUp

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nCoTuuHnBqEzNeRvhBivfsnCXBWfL0XS

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13BRtpbteMzUokRe5cPGhIfjokzyDfGDh

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18BvGvgaib5U2MbTphNae7pKWzN1uyaAx

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mazw9CQ97JgOW5ZTqXYSU1FGVHm8ndYs

Comment: please find above the links

Comment: A thousand excuses Majed, you found the solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the image address like this:

```
.firstPage {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "homePageImage1 homePageImage2"
}

.homePageImage1 {
  grid-area: homePageImage1;
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/gk0cBnrW/home-Page-Image1.png');
  width: 700px;
  height: 962px;
}

.homePageImage2 {
  grid-area: homePageImage2;
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/d0wx4TtR/home-Page-Image2.png");
  width: 666px;
  height: 962px;  
}

<div class="firstPage" style="width: 1366px;">
  <div class="homePageImage1">
  </div>
  <div class="homePageImage2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the fiddle and it works, but the html file on my browser does not show the images

Comment: Try to put http instead of https?